# How can I flatMapMany with multiple web calls and conditionally signal complete?

Tags: spring, spring-webflux, project-reactor, spring-reactor

I need to write a method which does

- Gets a `Location` header form an endpoint
- Generates a series of `Some` which each should retrieved from the `Location` fetched from the first endpoint.
- Need to return a `Flux<Some>`

Which looks like this.

```java
private WebClient client;

Flux<Some> getSome() {

    // Get the Location header from an endpoint
    client
            .post()
            .exchange()
            .map(r -> r.headers().header("Location"))

    // Now I need to keep invoking the Location endpoint for Some.class
    // And Some.class has an attribute for pending/completion status.

    // e.g.
    while (true)
        final Some some = client
            .get()
            .url(...) // the Location header value above
            .retrieve()
            .bodyToMono(Some.class)
            .block()
            ;
    }

}
```

How can I map the `Mono<String>` to a `Flux<Some>` while using the `Some#status` attribute for completion?

```java
    // should return Flux<Some>
    client
            .post()
            .exchange()
            .map(r -> r.headers().header("Location"))
            .flatMapMany(location -> {
                // invokes location while retrieved Some#status is not `completed`
                // @@?
            })
            ;
```

Answer (score 3):

inside the `flatMapMany`, perform the call that retrieves the `Location`. apply a `repeat().takeUntil(loc -> loc.complete())` to it (still inside the `flatMapMany` lambda)

Comment: Thank you for the answer, Sir. Would you please spend some time to kindly put an psudo code for me?